# ERROR: relation "log" does not exist at character 13 when install marquez and airflow

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, airflow, bitnami

i want to install marquez and airflow in docker but i got error when execution postgress. i use image bitnami/airflow

my error : [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bx5l.png)

docker-compose.yml

```
postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - AIRFLOW_USER=airflow
      - AIRFLOW_PASSWORD=airflow
      - AIRFLOW_DB=airflow
      - MARQUEZ_USER=marquez
      - MARQUEZ_PASSWORD=marquez
      - MARQUEZ_DB=marquez
      - EXAMPLE_USER=example
      - EXAMPLE_PASSWORD=example
      - EXAMPLE_DB=example
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - ./docker/init-db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db.sh
```

init-db.py

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: $ ./init-db.sh

set -eu

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "${POSTGRES_USER}" > /dev/null <<-EOSQL
  CREATE USER ${AIRFLOW_USER};
  ALTER USER ${AIRFLOW_USER} WITH PASSWORD '${AIRFLOW_PASSWORD}';
  CREATE DATABASE ${AIRFLOW_DB};
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE ${AIRFLOW_DB} TO ${AIRFLOW_USER};
  CREATE USER ${MARQUEZ_USER};
  ALTER USER ${MARQUEZ_USER} WITH PASSWORD '${MARQUEZ_PASSWORD}';
  CREATE DATABASE ${MARQUEZ_DB};
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE ${MARQUEZ_DB} TO ${MARQUEZ_USER};
  CREATE USER ${EXAMPLE_USER};
  ALTER USER ${EXAMPLE_USER} WITH PASSWORD '${EXAMPLE_PASSWORD}';
  CREATE DATABASE ${EXAMPLE_DB};
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE ${EXAMPLE_DB} TO ${EXAMPLE_USER};
EOSQL
```

data set in marquez not showed
[marquez](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfTyd.png)

Comment: it seems you have a problem in the script `init-db.sh`, can you add it to your question to understand what it does?

Comment: okay, i will add it

Answer (score 3):

When you create the airflow database for the first time, you need to call the command `airflow db init` which create multiple table (log, connections, dags, ...) in the airflow database.

If you want to add a volume for the database data, you can run this command once manually, but if you will clear the database from time to time, you can add a task to init your airflow db before starting airflow services, [here](https://github.com/hussein-awala/airflow-server/blob/main/docker-compose.yml#L68-L90) is an example of this service, you can check the project, it can help you to configure your airflow server.